# LINQ, Combine Items with a similar value

Tags: c#, linq

Assuming I had a collection like this..

```
var list = new List<Item>
{
 new Item
 { 
  Name = "Software",
  Price = 100
 },
 new Item
 {
  Name = "Software",
  Price = 200
 },
 new Item
 {
  Name = "Hardware",
  Price = 100
 }
};
```

And the 'Names' are not going to be known, I want to write a LINQ query that will return a list of everything with a matching name. I cannot use "Select", because the names, again, are not known at design time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, your question really isn't clear - particularly in terms of what's known or not known at compile time. You've given an example of the collection, but what are you trying to do with it? Give sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure whether you want to filter, or group the results.

If you want to filter, you can use [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) with a runtime-supplied name:

```
string nameToFind = GetTheNameToFind(); // Can come from user, config, etc
var matches = list.Where(item => item.Name == nameToFind);
```

If you want to group by all of the names (ie: have 2 software + 1 hardware element), you could use [Enumerable.GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx):

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(item => item.Name);

foreach(var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group {0}:", group.Key);
    foreach(var item in group)
         Console.WriteLine("    Item: {0} - {1}", item.Name, item.Price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this? You can use `Where` method to filter enumerable. 
`name` variable can be defined at runtime.

```
string name = "Software";
List<Item> newList = list.Where(item => item.Name == name).ToList();
```